# C# / Sqlite simple way to store query result as variable

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, function

I am semi-new to C# but in particular using Sqlite within C#, currently I have a SQlite DB setup fine in terms of it connects with the application well I am running windows form application and I have bound a table within the database to a datagrid view.

This is all fine I have a function setup to run queries where i pass the SQL statement as a string to the function and it runs it as a query.

I was wandering how I do I get a result back from the query I know obviosuly it will be somthing like

```
private string QueryResult(string query){
    connect
    run query
    read query 
    return result
}
```

All th examples I have seen use Sqlreader but I can't seem to get it work, I am really used to using PHP with SQL and that seems so much simpler than using it in C# can someone explain or point out somewhere I might be able to find a tutuorial or function that you can run any query in by passing it as a string and getting the result returned pretty simply? The results I need wont be arrays or huge things I am only looking to return 1 word strings or numbers at a time so I don't need anything complicated.

Please help me out I spent about 4 hours reading about this stuff last night and didn't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: Are you using a DataContext? Or ADO.NET? Is your Data in a DataTable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this, maybe it will help you:

```
public string QueryResult(string query)
{
    string result = "";
    SQLiteConnection sqlite = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=/path/to/file.db");
    try
    {
        sqlite.Open();  //Initiate connection to the db
        SQLiteCommand cmd = sqlite.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;  //set the passed query
        result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlite.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I will also try this when I get home this looks like the simplest one if it works might end up using this until implementing somthing more elegant.

Comment: Wow... this was pretty much copy and paste and it worked I tried to get it to work as Derek showed but I think I lack the understanding to pull it off it kept returning an object. anyway I will use this for now because it works I would like to get Derek's method working as it looks more interesting but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Heres a method that I have Used....

First off, build a class to represent a Table in your DataBase :-

```
public class Contact
    {
        public int ContactID { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Information { get; set; }   
    }
```

Then I load this Data into an IEnumerable List :-

```
public List<Contact> GetContacts()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Contacts]", Connection);
            Adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

            Connection.Open();
            Adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Adapter.Fill(dt);
            Connection.Close();

            var Contacts = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()

                            select new Contact
                            {
                                ContactID = row.Field<int>("ContactID"),
                                Surname = row.Field<string>("Surname"),
                                Forename = row.Field<string>("Forename"),
                                MobileNumber = row.Field<string>("MobileNumber"),
                                EmailAddress = row.Field<string>("EmailAddress"),
                                Information = row.Field<string>("Information")

                            }).ToList();



            return Contacts;
        }
```

In My application I create an Instance of this Object :-

```
   public List<Contact> contactData;
   contactData = dc.GetContacts();
```

I now have the power to manipulate the data using LINQ :-

```
var Query = ConactData.Where(item=> item.ContactID == 10)
            .Select(item=> item.Surname).toString();
```

You can use LINQ to query your Data and store it as Lists, Strings etc etc.

Hope This Helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had thought about making a class for this but I had no experience doing it and when I first tried it was with XML so slightly different but this looks exactly like the sort of thing I need I will test it tonight when I get home THANKS!

Comment: I'm very new to it myself, using LINQ is fantastic though and you will soon pick it up.

Comment: Yeah that looks like a more elegant solution than what I had in mind originally so it would probably be better to learn this than just use somthing simpler. I will give it a test tonight stuck in work just now :(

Comment: This is confusing I am converting this for use with SQLite the Adapter bit is giving me problems did you declare this somewhere?

Comment: Yes mate I did, Look up Data Adapters, I'm not at work so not got my coding at Hand... Sorry.

Comment: OK I sort of got it working I think its just I don't think I am getting the value correctly. Firstly when using SQLite is seems int needs to be Int64 or you get invalid cast type error but the return I got from your example query was "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[AEapp.Account,System.String]"

Comment: Wait is that returning an object I am converting to string.

Comment: Sorry Derek this is embarrassing I sort of deleted it all, and went with Anant Dabhi's example for simplicity, I actually got a book on c# delivered this morning and it has a couple chapters on LINQ so I am sure I will figure it out :) but I do appreciate you helping me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I do something like:

```
string CONNECTION_STRING = "Persist Security Info=False; Integrated Security = SSPI; Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Data Source=SERVERIP";

string query = "IF OBJECT_ID('TABLE_NAME') IS NOT NULL SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME";

using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader queryCommandReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Load(queryCommandReader);

            if (dataTable != null)
            {
                 if (dataTable.Rows != null)
                 {
                     if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                     {
                         String rowText = "";
                         rowText += dataTable.Rows[ROW_NUM] [COLUMN_NAME];                          
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ...
        }
        finally
        {
               ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

//in normal logic

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE condition) - (SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE condition)
```

---

//actual coding example

```
public void total_due()
                {
                    string query = "select (select sum(amount) from table_name where id>0 and amount>paid and [order no] like '" + textbox1.Text + "%' and [name] like '" + textbox2.Text + "%' and [date] like '" + textbox3.Text + "%' ) - (select sum(paid) from table_name where id>0 and amount>paid and [order no] like '" + textbox1.Text + "%' and [name] like '" + textbox2.Text + "%' and [date] like '" + textbox3.Text + "%' )";
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=server_name;Database=database_name;UID=sa;Password=password;");
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
                    due.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    con.Close();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this example.

Comment: You could have used String.Format to make life easier